# Does my motherboard support CAT 6?

Tags: motherboard, ethernet

My motherboard model is B365M DS3H and i want to connect a CAT6 Ethernet cable. Is it compatible with my mobo?
My hired plan is 500 Mpbs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can even connect a CAT6 cable to a 20 years old PC. The motherboard doesn't know it is CAT6. It's just a cable with high quality. It has a better shielding and certification. There are no electrical parts inside. It is just a cable.

Answer (score 2):

Does my motherboard support CAT 6?

From the spec [B365M DS3H (rev. 1.0) Specification | Motherboard - GIGABYTE Global](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B365M-DS3H-rev-10/sp#sp):

> Realtek® GbE LAN chip (10/100/1000 Mbit)

And from [Cat5 vs. Cat6 Ethernet Cables - What's Best for You | CDW](https://www.cdw.com/content/cdw/en/articles/hardware/cat5-vs-cat6-ethernet-cables.html)

> Cat6 Ethernet cables consist of four twisted pairs of copper wire and 250 MHz of bandwidth, supporting data transfer speeds of up to 10 Gbps (10GBASE-T) for distances up to approximately 180 feet.

So CAT 6 will support higher speeds than your motherboard and your plan speed

Answer (score 1):

Cat-6 is rated for transmissions up to 1GBit/s (actually: frequencies up to 250 MHz) and should work just fine.

But even a less expensive cable (say: Cat-5) should *work*. NIC might just down-regulate the transmission speed. So strictly speaking, even other cables are "compatible" in that sense. You just might not get maximum throughput.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question you actually asked (which I posit is very different to what you meant to ask) is NO.

A motherboard has no knowledge of cables/wires, and cat6 is a cable standard. Cables can not be directly connected to motherboards without an interface. (and there are multiple interfaces that can use cat6)

In the case of Ethernet, the ethernet cable may be cat6 - but it will have RJ45 jacks on each end. Provided the wiring of those jacks is correct, you can connect up the etherbet cable and it will work.

(There are other ways cat6 can be interfaced with some motherboards/computers - dialup, dsl, RS232, RS485, usb extnders spring to mind.  All will work fine with CAT6, but in none of these cases does tje cat6 directly interface with the motherboard.)